# How to get 1st week record from MYSQL for given month

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table called users with id, name and created date. Now i want to show user registered on 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th week of January separably. Like this i want to show for all month.  How can i achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

I tried

```
SELECT id, date, WEEK(date) weekno FROM user WHERE MONTH(date) in (4,5)
```

Comment: i want to list all users registered on first week of Jan.. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Hope it helps

SELECT id, name, created, WEEK(created) week
FROM user WHERE created_on BETWEEN start_date AND end_date ORDER BY week

Comment: Thank you!! But i don't have start and end date.

Answer (score 1):

Best way of learning is doing it yourself. You will have to read about `GROUP BY` and there are [several functions in MySQL you can use](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). You'll need `MONTH()` and `WEEK()` and probably `YEAR()`.

Have a try for yourself, if you still have problems, we are happy to help when you show us what you've tried and where exactly the problem is.

**UPDATE:**

You tried this:

```
SELECT id, date, WEEK(date) weekno FROM user WHERE MONTH(date) in '4,5'
```

Now,

```
SELECT ... WEEK(`date`)
```

Is `date` your column name? It's also a keyword of MySQL. Put it in backticks like I did or rename the column.

Have you read about the (optional) additional parameter of `WEEK()`? Is everything okay there for you?

```
... FROM user WHERE MONTH(date) in '4,5'
```

This is unfortunately wrong syntax. You have to write it like this:

```
... FROM user WHERE MONTH(`date`) IN (4, 5)
```

Also you have to consider that you might have data ranging over multiple years. If you don't add

```
... AND YEAR(`date`) = 2013
```

or something similar, you might get wrong data. If you're handling multiple years you should of course also add the year in the `SELECT` clause.

When you want to have simply information which user registered in the time period you specified in the `WHERE` clause, everything should be fine so far.

Comment: i tried with following query:- `SELECT id, date, WEEK(date) weekno FROM user WHERE MONTH(date) in (4,5)` MY final result should display the user registered on first week of April and May.. Please help !!

Comment: My main problem is how to pass the `where` condition for week number? i want the first week users only...

Comment: `WHERE ... AND WEEK(date) = 1` maybe?

Comment: Finally ended with below query:

`SELECT id, date, WEEK(date) weekno FROM users WHERE MONTH(date) in (4,5) AND YEAR(date)=YEAR(now()) AND date between ( SELECT LAST_DAY('2013-04-01' - interval 1 month)+ interval 1 day) and (SELECT LAST_DAY('2013-04-01' - interval 1 month)+ interval 7 day)`

@tombom any suggestion?

Comment: You don't need the `SELECT` in the `WHERE` clause:  SELECT id, `date`, 
 WEEK(date) weekno 
 FROM users 
 WHERE 
 MONTH(`date`) in (4,5) 
 AND YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
 AND `date` between (LAST_DAY('2013-04-01' - interval 1 month) + interval 1 day) AND (LAST_DAY('2013-04-01' - interval 1 month)+ interval 7 day)